# Assign result of a method to instance variable

Tags: ruby, methods, instance-variables, memoization

I often assign the result of a method to an instance variable in the initializer:

```
class MyExample
  def initialize
    @my_var = test_method
  end

  def test_method
    # does something
  end
end
```

Doing this in `initialize` instead of the method seems like a special case of memoization. I do this to avoid calling the method explicitly, which makes my code more readable. I also want to make sure that the method is only called once for the instance.

I have not found code that looks like this.

- Are there any downsides to doing this in the initializer apart from memoization in general?
- Would this be considered a bad practice in some way? Why?

Comment: In "instead of the method", which method does "the method" point to? It is not clear what you mean by "call the method explicitly".

Comment: I do not call **MyExample.new.test_method** explicitely. Instead I only write **MyExample.new** and the return value of test_method in the instance variable can be used in other methods (or accessed by attr_reader, not included in the example above).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is getting the result of your method into the instance variable without explicitly callling the method on an instance of the class, then your approach is reasonable. If your method body isn't too long, you can even make it inline inside the initializer.

If you want your method to be called once and only once, you can do something like this:

```
def test_method
   return if @your_method_has_been_called.nil?
   @test_method_has_been_called = true
   #perform your operations
end
```

However, if all you care is the fact that the operation is only performed once( may be it's an expensive operation) then you can use ||= operator inside your method and setting the instance variable there instead of inside initializer. Eg:

```
class MyExample
  def initialize
    test_method
  end

  def test_method
    @my_var ||=  1+1 # Replace your operation here
  end
end
```

In either case, since you don't wanna expose your result through your method, it's best to put it as a private method.